# Was the ark placed on the ground in the mishkan?

Tags: ark-aron-kodesh, vayakhel

When the priests carried the ark in the wilderness, did they place the ark on the ground inside the mishkan or was there a "stand" or "platform" on which it rested? Second question would be, What was the ark placed on in the temple?